# Use data.table to execute function over groups and report the results into another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, r-daisy

I have the following `data.table` which contains `group`s of individuals and some characteristics that describe them

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)

group<-(rep(1:10, sample(50:200, 10, replace=T)))
gender<-factor((sample(0:1, 1328, replace=T, prob=c(0.55, 0.45))))
country<-factor((sample(6030:6098, 1328, replace=T)))
ethnicity<-factor((sample(7040:7101, 1328, replace=T)))
yearbirth<-(sample(1950:1986, 1328, replace=T))
dt<-data.table(group, gender, country, ethnicity, yearbirth)
setkey(dt, group)
```

For each group, I would like to run the following function

```
library(cluster)
library(fpc)

ASW<-function(x){

  x<-as.data.frame(x)
  people<-length(as.vector(x[,1]))
  if (people==1){
    p=0
  } else {
    diss<-daisy(x, metric="gower")
    if (people/3<2) {
      maxclus=2      
    } else {
      maxclus<-round(people/3)
    }  
    asw <- numeric(maxclus)
    for (k in 2:maxclus) asw[[k]] <- pam(diss, k, diss=T) $ silinfo $ avg.width
    k.best <- which.max(asw)
    p<-asw[k.best]
  }  
  swg<-numeric(2)
  swg[1]<-id
  swg[2]<-p
  swg
}
```

[Note that `ASW` works using `data.frame`s internally because `daisy` does not accept `data.table`s]
As you can see, the function produces as a result the vector `swg`. Given that this function is going to be applied to every group in `dt`, it will produce a number of vectors equal to the number of groups. As a global result, I would like to produce another `data.table` (or even another `data.frame` is ok) which contains all the `swg` vectors `rbind`ed together. How can I do this? 
My attempt below shows how to apply the function to every group, but I wouldn't know how to store all the 'partial results' into another table.

```
dt[, ASW(.SD) [I don't know what should be here...] , by=group]
```

Hope the question is clear.
Many thanks in advance for your help!
Riccardo

Comment: Try `dt[, as.list(ASW(.SD)), by=group]`